# Pair class in Map reduce throwing error

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

Why Pair class is throwing an error in below code

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
 import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
 import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.*;

 public static class PrizeMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Pair>{

 int rating = 0;
 Text CustID;
 IntWritable r;
 Text MovieID;
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text line, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line1 = line.toString();
        String [] fields = line1.split(":");
        if(fields.length > 1)
             {
             String Movieid = fields[0];
             String line2 = fields[1];
             String [] splitline = line2.split(",");
             String Custid = splitline[0];
             int rate = Integer.parseInt(splitline[1]);
             r = new IntWritable(rate);
             CustID = new Text(Custid);
             MovieID = new Text(Movieid);
             // CustID.set(Custid);
             //MovieID.set(Movieid);
             context.write(MovieID,new Pair(CustID,r));
             }
             else
             {
             return;
             }
  }
}

public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,Pair,Text,Pair> {
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
public void reduce(Text key, Pair values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(key, values);
}
```

Errors:
    cannot find symbol
        [javac]        extends Mapper{
        [javac]                                                 ^
        [javac]   symbol:   class Pair
        [javac]   location: 
    cannot find symbol
        [javac]        extends Reducer {
        [javac]                             ^
        [javac]   symbol:   class Pair

Comment: Well do you have an import for `Pair`? You haven't shown *any* imports in your (badly indented) code.

Comment: What is "Pair"? I don't think there is such a class in Hadoop, extending Writable. So, it should be a class that you have defined and it should also extend Writable since it is used as a value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have added import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.* statement (browsed on net )but it is throwing error, can you please suggest which import statement i need to add.

Comment: Thanks a lot JonSkeet Skeet and @Vefthym, your suggestion help me a lot. I want to accept your suggestions as answer but its not appearing as answer. I guess may be bcoz its comment well thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: @Manvi I have added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that `Pair` is a class that you have defined, since it is not one of the standard Hadoop Writable classes.

The problem is that you do not import it, as Jon Skeet mentions in his comment.

However, keep in mind, that since you are using it as a reduce output value, it should also be a class that implements the [Writable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html) interface.